# How to compare two dates to have validation functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

Hi I am working on a project where I date field.

I need to have validation for the same field.

1) Should allow user to select previous dates or year. 
2) But not allow user to select future date.

I have used the below code and it works fine for only present year. 
Can anyone help me to achive it.

```
 $scope.$watch('date', function(val) {
   var dateNewOnCreatessssss = $scope.convertedTimeToSend(new Date());
   console.log("dateNewOnCreatessssss", dateNewOnCreatessssss);
   $scope.convertedTimeToSend = function(timestamp) {
     var c = moment(timestamp).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
     return c;
   };
   if (val) {
     $scope.dateErrorMsg = false;
   }
   var dateNewOnCreatessssssll = $scope.convertedTimeToSend(val);
   console.log("dateNewOnCreatessssssll", dateNewOnCreatessssssll);
   if (dateNewOnCreatessssssll > dateNewOnCreatessssss) {
     $scope.dateErrorMsgsssssss = true;
     $scope.newReceiptSaveBtn = "true";
   } else {
     $scope.dateErrorMsgsssssss = false;
     $scope.newReceiptSaveBtn = "false";
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well m8, your code is a big mess. Just use all the good stuff provided by [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to make it work. Finaly this function should look like this simple snippet:

```
$scope.$watch('date', function(val) {
    if (val) {

        //Init
        var today = new moment();
        var selectedDate = new moment(val);

        if(selectedDate.isBefore(today)){
            $scope.dateErrorMsg = false;
            $scope.newReceiptSaveBtn = "false";

        } else {
            $scope.dateErrorMsg = true;
            $scope.newReceiptSaveBtn = "true";
        }
    }
});
```

---

While the example above is focusing a solution based on your codes it would be much better to create a pure AngularJS handling like in this approach:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

    //Init
    $scope.date  = new moment()._d;
    $scope.error = false;
    
    $scope.validateDate = function () {
    
        //Init
        var today = new moment();
        var selectedDate = new moment($scope.date);
        
        if(selectedDate.isBefore(today)){
            $scope.error = false;
        } else {
            $scope.error = true;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.error {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="date" 
           ng-model="date" 
           ng-change="validateDate()" 
           ng-class="{ 'error': error }" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lin.. :)

Comment: @User123 glad to help.

Comment: I am sorry to say this but I am not able to proceed further with 26-03-2016. getting error. Can you please help me on this

Comment: @User123 wow m8, thanks for removing the tick. What exactly is your problem "further with 26-03-2016" ?

Comment: See if I select previous year till March 02 it is working fine. But if I select future date like March 04 2016 it will not accept.

Comment: this is what you want `2) But not allow user to select future date.` right? I modified the code so all future dates will getting an error. Please run the snippet in my answer an check.

Comment: Yea but I am facing issue with some of the prev mentioned example. If that works fine thn I wud love to accept your answer

Comment: @User123 dont know whats wrong. `error` is `true` if the user enters a date in the future. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137064/discussion-between-user123-and-lin).